# SQL recursive array

Tags: sql, select, hive

Is there a way to iterate through ranges to have a big query? If not I will have to make a python script to execute every possibility.

I need to calculate an average of defaulter people depending their age and range salary... I made it just with one and it works, but is there a way to do the whole and big query at once?

**Age**: [21, 30], [31, 40], [41, 50], [51, 60], [61, 70], [71, 80], [81, ...]

**Salary**: [0, 200], [201, 500], [501, 1000], [1001, 1500], [1501, 2000], [2001, 2500], [2501, 3000], [3001, 3500], [3501, 4000], [4001, 5000], [5001, 6000], [6001, 10000], [10001, ...]

I have the next query that works properly for age[30, 40] and salary[1500-2000].

```
SELECT 
 (COUNT(*) * 100)/ (SELECT 
                    COUNT(*) 
                   FROM Client
                   WHERE (Age BETWEEN 30 AND 40) 
                   AND (Salary BETWEEN 1500 AND 2000)) AS percentage
FROM Client
WHERE (Age BETWEEN 30 AND 40)
AND (Salary BETWEEN 1500 AND 2000)
AND Defaulter = 1
GROUP BY Defaulter
```

Result is:

```
Defaulters->             68
Clients  at range->     114
percentage->             59
```

Is there a way to make all of this one after another N times?

Thank you

**EDIT**:

```
CREATE TABLE Client
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
Salary int,
Age int,
Defaulter int
);
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: you can use a cursor with dynamic sql and enter the results into a temp table and query from that - but its a tad messy

Comment: Not sure which RDBMS you are using, but one way is to create a procedure and pass in the parameters for the age ranges and salary ranges.

Comment: dbajtr & Donal  - Linear thinking...SQL works best as set-based and will perform it's best when you code as such.

Comment: Your post makes no sense - for start, there is no way your query works in Hive. **(1)** make up your mind regarding the database you are using. **(2)** Edit your post and supply a reasonable data sample, including required result, both in table format.

Answer (score 1):

SQL languages vary from server to server, so I'm leaving my answer psuedo.

Create 2 reference tables.

```
Table Ages as (age_display varchar(20),age_start_range int, age_end_range int).  

Table salaries as (sal_display varchar(20), sal_start_range int, sal_end_range int)
```

In your join statement:

```
FROM Client c inner join ages a on c.age > age_start_range  and c.age < age_end_range
inner join salaries s on c.salary > sal_start_range and c.salary < sal_end_range
```

You can now use the 'Display' columns in the table in your select and group by statements.

Can't go much further than that without knowing your DB

Comment: With this query (I know is pseudo code) I will get all age-salary possibilities?

Comment: Correct.  You are turning the age and salary into dimensions.   Your select statement would be along the lines of  select age_display, salary_display, percentage_logic   from.. where.. group by age_display,salary_display

Comment: Heh, your percentage calc is a bit weird...you will want a subquery to return total counts so you can get your count of defaults / total count.  What database are you using?

Comment: Is HQL (but as you may noticed I am not really good at it...) What I use is cloudera.com website and the warehouse system is HIVE

Answer (score -1):

Create a table with columns for the minimum and maximum ages, and another table with the minimum and maximum salaries.  These can be temporary or permanent tables.  Cross join them with your `Client` table, and reference the age and salary columns in your query instead of the hard-coded values that you are currently using.